# 2 url's in powershell with cmd

Tags: powershell, cmd, task, schedule

I have create the following schedule task but I would like to add a second url which will run after the end of the first. Could anyone help με how can I do it??

Thanks in advance.

```
schtasks /create /tn "My Task Title" /tr "powershell -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted -Command \"(New-Object Net.WebClient).DownloadString(\\\"Url1\\\")\"" /sc DAILY /ru username /rp pass
```

Comment: You can put other commands in there using semicolons as long as it is all quoted and escaped properly. Depending on how complicated this gets you might consider putting it into a script and using the `-File` argument of PowerShell

Comment: Personally I'd go the route of listing URLs separated by commas and then piping that to a ForEach loop that runs your download.

Comment: I think these commands should be moved into a .ps1 file that gets executed. Makes it easier to maintain.

Comment: I think someone here should post their suggestion as an answer (perhaps with some additional explanation on `-File foo.ps1` and `-Command "&{bar}"`) ... ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple URLs it would be best to move some of the logic into a PowerShell script file to push some of the logic away from the command line. Not that you could put this all in the command line but for ease and readability using the `-File` parameter of powershell would be a better way to go. First you would need to create a file called "Get-WebStrings.ps1" with the following contents.

```
# Check to be sure we have at least one argument.
If($args.Count -gt 0){
    # Treat each argument as a URL that we need to download. 
    ForEach($singleURL in $args){
        # Download the string
        (New-Object Net.WebClient).DownloadString($singleURL)
        # Optional depending on your needs
        # (New-Object Net.WebClient).DownloadString($singleURL) | Out-Null
    }
}
```

What this script will do it take the arguments sent to it as treat each one as a url and download the data. By default this would output to console. If merely performing the download is all you wish then you could pipe the output into `Out-Null` (*see commented code above*).

Next you would need to create the task in the command line much like you have already done. **Note** that this file needs to be accessible on the local system where the task is being called! Each URL is placed inside single quotes in the string.

```
schtasks /create /tn "My Task Title" /tr "powershell -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted -File 'C:\Temp\Get-WebStrings.ps1' 'https://www.google.com' 'http://www.purple.com'" /sc daily /ru username /rp pass
```

If you were to look at the Action inside Task Scheduler it would look like this after that was run.

```
-ExecutionPolicy unrestricted -File "C:\Temp\Get-WebStrings.ps1" "https:\\www.google.com" "https:\\employee.firstair.ca"
```